# How to setup HA when the masters have the same hostname?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to setup an HA cluster with 2 masters. The masters have the same hostname but different domain names, for instance:
- foo.domain1.tld
- foo.domain2.tld

We configured the high availability of the controller and scheduler with the option `--leader-elect=true`. And afaik the way it works is by setting a key in etcd (by default kube-scheduler).
It can be seen in the scheduler logs

`I0926 15:29:53.926628       1 event.go:218] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Endpoints", Namespace:"kube-system", Name:"kube-scheduler", UID:"8b6d7117-a2cf-11e7-a32d-549f351a92e0", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"3315810", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'LeaderElection' foo became leader`

I checked the key directly into etcd and the value written is the hostname, not the fqdn. So the elected master will always be `foo` though the masters have different domain names : `domain1.tld` `domain2.tld`.

Is there a way to define another value for the lock, let's say the fqdn of the host instead of its hostname ? Is there any other workaround such as `--hostname-override` option ?
Otherwise do you think that'd be wise to create a github issue ?

Thank you !
Smana

Comment: Start a github issue. The FQDN should be an allowed and configurable value.